# How to get NextAuth session in ApolloServer context

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using `apollo-server-micro` and `next-auth` I would like to pass the user's session to the context so that it can be used in graphql resolvers. Problem is that ApolloServer does not seem to be passing credentials to be used by NextAuth's `getSession()` function.

```
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-micro";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import Cors from "micro-cors";

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req }) => { // <-- request object contains no credentials
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    return { session };
  },
});


export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const startServer = apolloServer.start();

const cors = Cors();

export default cors(async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.end();
    return false;
  }
  await startServer;
  await apolloServer.createHandler({
    path: "/api/graphql",
  })(req, res);
});
```

I have looked everywhere for the answer to this but cannot seem to find it. How can NextAuth credentials be passed to `ApolloServer` so that `session` does not return `null`?